# Rename tag [robomongo] >> [robo-3t]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I would like to suggest to add a tag synonyms:

[robomongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robomongo) >> [robo-3t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robo-3t)

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613292/meteor-method-users-insert-not-found), and checking about `robo-3t` I saw [here](https://robomongo.org) its name is now changed.

Answer (score 1):

[robo3t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robo3t) was already present, so I mapped [robomongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robomongo) to that instead of creating a new tag all by itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of it.